# Applying filtering to ObservableCollection items without allocating additional memory for each filtered item

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

.Net Maui app. I want to have a `SearchBar` where user is able to enter search text and ListView or any other view with `ItemsSource` to react immediately by filtering out any not matched item. I do not want to re-create ObservableCollection of items each time user changes one single symbol in the search bar since it re-allocates memory for the filtered list of items, and the list could be long.

I've found how this handled by syncfuntion list control: https://help.syncfusion.com/maui/listview/filtering. Filter there applied "on the run" to each item in the list while binding it to the `ItemsSource` of a `View`, so no new collection is created for the search params, same collection is used but with different param on "per item" bases. You can achieve similar effect if you use `IEnumerable` with custom `Where` statement, but then you lost benefits of your collection being "observable". Any ideas on how to resolve this without syncfusion's listview control?

Comment: do you actually have a memory issue, or are you trying to avoid one?  Unless you are dealing with huge classes or lists this seems like something you can just let the garbage collector handle.

Comment: I did not test it yet, but Garbage Collection won't necessary keep up with the frequency of collection re-creation since it should react on every keyboard button press, and collection is long: hundreds of items

Comment: even if you have dozens of lists being created temporarily, they will all contain references to the same set of objects.  I really think you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: object are the same, right, but still there will be hundreds or thousands of new references created every second while user typing, depending on how fast user types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Filter" by binding `IsVisible` of `ItemTemplate`s view to a bool that you set.

```xml
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <SomeLayoutOrViewHere IsVisible="{Binding Show}" ...
...
```

```cs
public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems ...

void ApplyFilter(...)
{
  foreach (MyItem item in MyItems)
  {
    item.Show = ...;
  }
}


public class MyItem : ObservableObject
{
  public bool Show { get => show; set => SetProperty(ref show, value); }
  private bool show;
  ...
}
```

Comment: this solution is noticeably faster. When I recreated ObservableCollection, my Android Emulator lagged few sec when I was typing in the SearchBar